# Querying data over linked server from SQL Azure RLS database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, linked-server

I want to get data via a linked server from SQL Azure which is using Row-Level Security. The problem appears that the query does not return any data.

If I execute the same query directly on SQL Azure, I get the data.

**{SQL query for linked server} - Not working**

```
EXEC SP_SET_SESSION_CONTEXT @key=N'TenantId', @value='XXX'
SELECT * FROM [AHPRO].[AllHoursProduction].[dbo].[User]
```

**{SQL query for SQL Azure} - Working**

```
EXEC SP_SET_SESSION_CONTEXT @key=N'TenantId' ,@value='XXX'
select * from [AllHoursProduction].[dbo].[User]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Linked Server you have a local Session and a remote Session.  You're setting a property in your Local Session and it has no effect on your remote session.

You could do something like

```
exec('
EXEC SP_SET_SESSION_CONTEXT @key=N''TenantId'' ,@value=''XXX''
select * from [AllHoursProduction].[dbo].[User]
') at AHPRO
```

to run the whole batch at the linked server.